# Python - Subprocess with STDIN and STDOUT

Tags: python, subprocess, stdout, stdin

I would like to pass a byte-object from file A.py to B.py where it is incremented by 1 and then passed back. Currently I have the following code and whenever I run `python A.py`, the program does not print anything. I feel like the problem is in file B.py though I am not sure.

**A.py**

```
import subprocess
import struct

door = subprocess.Popen(['python','B.py'], stdin=subprocess.PIPE, stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
door.stdin.write(struct.pack(">B", 0))
door.stdin.flush()
print(struct.unpack(">B", door.stdout.read()))
```

**B.py**

```
import sys
import struct

my_input = sys.stdin.buffer.read()
nbr = struct.unpack(">B", my_input)
sys.stdout.buffer.write(struct.pack(">B",nbr+1))
sys.stdout.buffer.flush()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `B.py` you didn't specify how many bytes to read. It defaults to reading until it gets EOF, which won't happen until `A.py` closes the pipe.

So either close the pipe in `A.py` after writing (replace `door.stdin.flush()` with `close(door.stdin)`, or have `B.py` just read the number of bytes it needs.

```
my_input = sys.stdin.buffer.read(struct.calcsize(">B"))
```

Comment: Is there a way to politely exit B.py only when A.py closes its pipes to B.py?

Comment: `B.py` can call `sys.stdin.buffer.read()` again to wait for EOF.